# JSR-303 bean validation with Groovy traits (Hibernate Validator)

Tags: groovy, jackson, bean-validation

I run into a problem with JSR-303 bean validation with a **Groovy** class that implements Traits with additional fields (plus their constraints). Let me show you a simple example. I have a class called `ClientInfo` which looks like this:

```
class ClientInfo implements AddressInfo, ContactInfo, BusinessEntity { }
```

It implements 3 traits that provides additional information. `AddressInfo` may look like this:

```
trait AddressInfo {
    @Size(max = 128)
    @SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE)
    String contactName

    @Size(max = 255)
    @SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE)
    String addressLine1

    @Size(max = 255)
    @SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE)
    String addressLine2

    @Size(max = 32)
    @SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE)
    String postalCode

    @Size(max = 64)
    @SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE)
    String city

    @Size(max = 3)
    @SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE)
    String countryCode
}
```

So far everything looks good. The problem shows up when the constraint validation fails. For example, if `countryCode` field fails during `ClientInfo` instance validation, it holds error message under the `AddressInfo__countryCode` field name:

```
{"AddressInfo__countryCode":"size must be between 0 and 3"}
```

It is caused by the fact that the fields that come from the trait are compiled into e.g. `AddressInfo__countryCode`, `AddressInfo__addressLine1` and so one, providing getters and setters for those fields.

I tried to use `Jackson` annotations like `@JsonProperty('countryCode')` over the `countryCode` field in the `AddressInfo` trait, but it didn't help (the annotation was added to compiled class).

**My question is:** is it possible to use e.g. Jackson property mappers to render field names provided in `@JsonProperty('...')` annotation for the fields provided by implemented trait? I will really appreciate your help.

PS: I'm using `'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final'` bean validation implementation (maybe this one should be change).

Comment: Can't you use `@JsonProperty('AddressInfo__countryCode')` ?

Comment: I think the problem is you're trying to use a Trait to add member properties to an object... which is not the purpose.  A Trait's members are converted that way in order to keep them from being used directly, an attempt to keep them "private".  You can add a method, perhaps, called "getAddress" which would return a map of the value stored in those "private" fields.  Look into the difference between a "isA" relationship (which is Trait-ish) vs. a "hasA" relationship, which seems to be what you're attempting.